# Dependence of solubility on pH

Tags: solubility

I am studying the effect that pH has on solubility of metal salts. One example I came across is the idea that the solubility of $\ce{PbI2}$ is not strongly affected by the addition of strong acid to solution because $\ce{PbI2}$ contains the conjugate base of a strong acid ($\ce{HI}$). Online references explain that this makes sense, since the presence of additional $\ce{H+}$ ions won't successfully pull the $\ce{I-}$ ions out of solution (since $\ce{HI}$) is a strong acid that wants to dissociate).

However, is this line of reasoning actually correct? For example, what if the strong acid added to solution is $\ce{HI}$ itself? Wouldn't that lead to the presence of additional $\ce{I-}$ ions that increase the reaction quotient above $K_\text{sp}$ and thereby cause the solubility to decrease (more solid to precipitate out)?

I suppose the general question is: how should I think about the role of pH on solubility when the acid being added to tune the pH contains a compound that is being dissolved from the solid in the first place?

Comment: It's no pH, but ligands that change that are important.

Comment: pH and solubility of metal salts have very little connection. The rest is all extrapolation.

Comment: There can be impact of pH on PbI2 solubility, if Pb^2+(aq) are being turned to something else, like PbOH+(aq) or Pb(OH)2(s).